# YouTube Data API: daily requests went from 2.7Mn to 43Mn in one day

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I started seeing 404 daily quota reached all of sudden so I went to my API console to check the logs.
What I found there was just today, I got 43Mn requests from my API key, while the number of daily average requests was about 2.5Mn. Does it mean someone is doing something malicious with my API key? How do I investigate the issue?

Note: I am using the youtube API key in my [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-music/ehebnoicojclpjjblbacdjmpjpkocmml)

Comment: Is it possible you're app has become more popular? Mentioned on a popular site perhaps? Do you have/get download counts?

Comment: No. The number of users is steady.

Comment: is it the same problem of this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/25657111/2274530 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a major bug. Same problem here - quota usage spiked like crazy starting on Sept. 3 and requests now cost WAY more than the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) [states](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

Someone reported it as a defect in their bug tracking system. I suggest everyone affected go there and star the defect to help call attention to it:

- https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6623&q=label%3AAPI-YouTube&sort=-id&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary