# Youtube API v3 every single request is counted as 300 requests

Tags: youtube-api

My application suddenly started to get error "Daily Limit Exceeded". Then I checked the count of request, I found out that every 1 request is counted as 300 requests. Whats wrong? This problem exists for the last 24 hours or so.

Look at the Picture please, at the bottom it shows the real request number 88. Whats wrong with the one on the top?
[image]

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost?hl=fr

Comment: I checked it and my request cost should be only 2. And as I said I had no problems with limit, I was not even using half of the limit.

Comment: I have same problem, I haven't changed anything in my application and it started to count request more than 100, instead of 2. My application was ending the day with 8 millions of total request, but now its using 50 millions in the morning without an unexpected user growth.

Comment: Same problem here.. App became unusable because of quota limits.. Is there somewhere where we can file a bug?

Comment: @cujo30227 https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6623&q=label%3AAPI-YouTube&sort=-id&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a quota cost increase, it's temporarily reverted. We'll announce cost changes in http://apiblog.youtube.com/ and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history going forward.