# How to use API KEY with YouTube in angularjs and list videos in a playlist?

Tags: angularjs, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to list a bunch of videos from YouTube in my mobile app using angularjs.
Preferrably I'd like to list all videos of a user/channels specific playlist.

I've gotten the API KEY from Google Developer Console but I don't understand how and where to use it. In this documentation they only go over the oauth method. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests
I tried using the example code straight up from that documentation only to get a message saying I have to authenticate first.

I'd really appreciate some help into this. 
How do authenticate using the api key and secondly how to make the request to get the videos in a playlist.

ps. I'm a newbie developer and I'm using angularjs and ionic framework for my first learning project. I'm fresh out of Codeschool's courses in css, jquery, javascript, backbone and angular. ds.
Thanks!

Comment: just for list the videos of channel you don't need to be authenticate

Comment: oh, cool! Then I just have to figure out how to request the list and show it :)

Answer (score 15):

## 1. How to use the API

If you want videos of a channel you need to use the [YouTube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Use `youtube.search.list`

with the parameters :

```
part=id, snippet
channelId=ID OF THE CHANNEL
order=date
type=video
```

**How to find ID of a YouTube Channel ?**

You can find the id of a channel with his channel name with http://mpgn.github.io/YTC-ID/

More information of `youtube.search.list` right [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search).

This is a **[live demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252C%20snippet&channelId=UCqhNRDQE_fqBDBwsvmT8cTg&order=date&type=video&_h=2&)**.

## 2. With Javascript ?

- First, you need to creat a project in [console.google.developers](https://console.developers.google.com).
- Enable the API YouTube API V3 (set to on).
- In credential part, creat a public access key.

Also if it's a public app, you may interest by : [How to protect my public API key ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670763/2274530)

This is the basic code to get the videos of a channel :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

function googleApiClientReady() {

    var apiKey = 'your api key';

    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

        request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'snippet',
            channelId: 'UCqhNRDQE_fqBDBwsvmT8cTg',
            order: 'date',
            type: 'video'

        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
                console.log(response);

        });
    });

}
  </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## 3. With AngularJS  ?

With AngularJS you need to creat a service 'google' for example, and you can use the service in your controllers.

An sample example : https://gist.github.com/jakemmarsh/5809963
You don't need the part with authentification.
Using `deferred` is important in this case.

Example in the **controller**

```
'use strict';

function init() {
    window.initGapi(); // Calls the init function defined on the window
}
angular.module('team')
    .controller('VideosCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $sce, googleService) {

        $window.initGapi = function() {
            $scope.$apply($scope.getChannel);
        };

        $scope.getChannel = function () {
            googleService.googleApiClientReady().then(function (data) {
                $scope.channel = data;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Failed: ' + error)
            });
        };
    });
```

Example in the **service** googleService

```
.service('googleService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    this.googleApiClientReady = function () {
        gapi.client.setApiKey('YOU API KEY');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                part: 'snippet',
                playlistId: 'PLila01eYiSBjOtR8oqXkY0i5c1QS6k2Mu',
                maxResults: 8
            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.result);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}])
```

You need to add this line to your index.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

Hope it's help you !

Comment: Thanks @martialdidi! But now I'm stuck...
I made it fine to part 3. I created a service but then I don't know how to use the controller to get the data ondo the DOM. Can you help out?

Comment: you mean you don't know how to use AngularJS ?

Comment: Haha yes. I'm a newbie developer and I'm using angularjs and ionic framework for my first learning project. I'm fresh out of Codeschool's courses in css, jquery, javascript, backbone and angular. Sorry, I forgot to mention my n00b status in this question. I usually do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't the api key would expose to public if the program is done this way? Any idea to make these confidential information stay confidential?

Comment: @JustinMoh part 2: "Also if it's a public app, you may interest by : How to protect my public API key ?"

Comment: @mpgn can you please help me to upload video i am not able to upload it. i am posting my question soon as ill git your replay

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Google APIs Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) so that `gapi` object will be defined and examples from google will work.
Include this in the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

And than define callback which will proceed with authorization and your logic:

```
googleApiClientReady = function() {
  gapi.auth.init(function() {
    // Other code following the example
  });
}
```

In general as per [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) there are

> 1. The application loads the JavaScript client library.
> 2. The application references its API key, which authenticates the application with Google services.
> 3. If the application needs access to the user's personal information, it opens a session with a Google auth server. The auth server opens a dialog box which prompts the user to authorize the use of personal information.
> 4. The application loads the API for the Google service.
> 5. The application initializes a request object (also called a service object) that specifies the data to be returned by the API.
> 6. The application executes the request and processes the data returned by the API.

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXyoZHo0pZ8w4EA0MOxB?p=preview) of basic google API authorization process