# how to display youtube thumbnail image from url with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api, angularjs-controller

I just start to using angularjs and I want to display youtube thumbnail image from the youtube video url ... is there a way to display video thumbnail when people insert url in input and then click the button,

```
PLUNKER
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9SBbTaDONuNXvOQ7lkWe?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube provide default thumbnail image of its video.

You can use below sample URL to create thumbnail image.

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

Where you need to search id from the given url & create url like above will give you thumbnail image.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = [];

    $scope.addInput = function() {
      $scope.inputs.push({
        field: ''
      });
    }

    $scope.removeInput = function(index) {
      $scope.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $scope.set2 = function($ayd) {
      var thumb = getParameterByName(this.input.ayd, 'v'),
        url = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + thumb + '/default.jpg';
      this.thumb = url
    }

    function getParameterByName(url, name) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
      return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
  }
]);
```

There many ways to do this, you can refer [**from here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/2435473)

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPvWitN1LcDrrus1O3DV?p=preview) Here

Comment: thank you very much it works like a charm ,,,, can I also use vimeo with same input???

Comment: @AydIn don;t sure vimeo has such feature or not

Comment: or can I display the youtube video and vimeo video instead of the image? like in iframe

Comment: yes you could do that..eaisly..to get good UI controller you should go for some plugin

Comment: a better whay is to use the official API of YouTube. Imagine one day they change the url of the image...

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9eCqagoeC77Elo2odW1?p=preview) is a simple Plunker that pulls the Youtube ID from the inputted URL with a filter and then applies the image url to the image source using the Youtube provided [image paths](http://www.joshuawinn.com/get-the-thumbnails-of-a-youtube-video-standard-url-and-file-names/).

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.filter('getVideoId', function() {
    return function(input) {

     // get video id
     var output = input.substr(input.indexOf("=") + 1);

     return output;
   }
})
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="input.url" placeholder="Youtube URL" />
      <img class="ythumb" ng-src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{input.url | getVideoId}}/0.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: if I want to use vimeo too how can I use with this?

Comment: You would have to use the Vimeo API. It isn't as easy as Youtube.

Answer (score 2):

With **AngularJS**

- First, you need to creat a project in [console.google.developers](https://console.developers.google.com).
- Enable the API YouTube API V3 (set to on).
- In credential part, creat a public access key.

In the controller `VideoCtrl` for example:

```
'use strict';

function init() {
    window.initGapi(); // Calls the init function defined on the window
}

angular.module('team')
    .service('googleService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        this.googleApiClientReady = function () {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR API KEY');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                    part: 'snippet',
                    playlistId: 'PLila01eYiSBjOtR8oqXkY0i5c1QS6k2Mu',
                    maxResults: 8
                });
                request.execute(function(response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.result);
                });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }])
    .controller('VideosCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $sce, googleService) {

        $window.initGapi = function() {
            $scope.$apply($scope.getChannel);
        };

        $scope.getChannel = function () {
            googleService.googleApiClientReady().then(function (data) {
                $scope.channel = data;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Failed: ' + error)
            });
        };
    });
```

And don't forget to `init` the API. Add this line at the end of your `index.html`

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

For beginners you may be interested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25783421/2274530

Answer (score 1):

this works for me :D

```
<video>
  <source [src]="yourvideo.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const YOUTUBE_API_KEY = 'abcd--z';
const YOUTUBE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
```

**class**

```
export class VideoDetail {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  thumbnailUrl: string;
  videoUrl: string;

  constructor(obj?: any) {
      this.id = obj && obj.id || null;
      this.title = obj && obj.title || null;
      this.description = obj && obj.description || null;
      this.thumbnailUrl = obj && obj.thumbnailUrl || null;
      this.videoUrl = obj && obj.videoUrl || `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${this.id}`;
  }
}
```

**component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-listing',
  templateUrl: './video-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-listing.component.scss']
})
export class VideoListingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    // bpLmn-oO60E is the videoId of video
    this.search("bpLmn-oO60E").subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
  search(query: string): Observable<VideoDetail[]> {
    const params: string = [
      `q=${query}`,
      `key=${YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`,
      `part=snippet`,
      `type=video`,
      `maxResults=10`
    ].join('&');

    const queryUrl = `${YOUTUBE_API_URL}?${params}`;

    return this.http.get(queryUrl).pipe(map(response => {
      return response['items'].map(item => {
        return new VideoDetail({
          id: item.id.videoId,
          title: item.snippet.title,
          description: item.snippet.description,
          thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
        });
      });
    }));
  }
}
```