# AngularJS with GoogleAPI Services

Tags: angularjs, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using `https://github.com/christiansmith/ngGAPI` this Services which helps me for the Google API Services V3 for Youtube. Though I have followed the instruction. Taken dependency as well. but it's not working. eg.

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        "gapi"
    ])
  .value('GoogleApp', {
        apiKey: 'API_KEY',
        clientId: 'NUMBERS.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scopes: [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
        ]
    })
   .controller('YoutubeController', ['$scope', 'Video', "Youtube", "GAPI",
    function ($scope, Video, Youtube, GAPI) {
        GAPI.init();
        $scope.videos = Youtube.search({part: 'snippet', q: 'Sample Text to Search'})
    }]);
```

Included Google Apis link as well. But it's giving me the error of `GAPI.app.oauthToken is undefined` or sometimes `gapi.auth is undefined` Please help

I am doing this all on local-server `http://localhost:3000/#/`

Comment: Have you initialized Google api? This is how I do it async: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59678/simple-async-google-maps-initializer-with-angularjs

Comment: Yes I did, in my controller. Let me edit my question to add controller sample.

Comment: if it tells you something is not defined, it is likely initialization problem

Comment: I know. How to initialize it in different way, when I have already done with single way.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783421/2274530