# Video Upload In Youtube APi using Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I need to upload video to youtube using APi.Is it possible in Youtube API?

Please give one example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This example is taken directly from the [official YouTube Data API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert), and shows how to perform the following functions:

1. It retrieves the channel name and thumbnail of the authenticated user's channel using the API's channels.list method.
2. It handles the video upload to YouTube using the resumable upload protocol.
3. It polls for the uploaded video's upload and processing status using the API's videos.list method by setting the part parameter value to status.

Using the [Javascript Client API](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client):

```
/*
Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

var signinCallback = function (result){
  if(result.access_token) {
    var uploadVideo = new UploadVideo();
    uploadVideo.ready(result.access_token);
  }
};

var STATUS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 60 * 1000; // One minute.


/**
 * YouTube video uploader class
 *
 * @constructor
 */
var UploadVideo = function() {
  /**
   * The array of tags for the new YouTube video.
   *
   * @attribute tags
   * @type Array.<string>
   * @default ['google-cors-upload']
   */
  this.tags = ['youtube-cors-upload'];

  /**
   * The numeric YouTube
   * [category id](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videoCategories.list?part=snippet®ionCode=us).
   *
   * @attribute categoryId
   * @type number
   * @default 22
   */
  this.categoryId = 22;

  /**
   * The id of the new video.
   *
   * @attribute videoId
   * @type string
   * @default ''
   */
  this.videoId = '';

  this.uploadStartTime = 0;
};


UploadVideo.prototype.ready = function(accessToken) {
  this.accessToken = accessToken;
  this.gapi = gapi;
  this.authenticated = true;
  this.gapi.client.request({
    path: '/youtube/v3/channels',
    params: {
      part: 'snippet',
      mine: true
    },
    callback: function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
        console.log(response.error.message);
      } else {
        $('#channel-name').text(response.items[0].snippet.title);
        $('#channel-thumbnail').attr('src', response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);

        $('.pre-sign-in').hide();
        $('.post-sign-in').show();
      }
    }.bind(this)
  });
  $('#button').on("click", this.handleUploadClicked.bind(this));
};

/**
 * Uploads a video file to YouTube.
 *
 * @method uploadFile
 * @param {object} file File object corresponding to the video to upload.
 */
UploadVideo.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {
  var metadata = {
    snippet: {
      title: $('#title').val(),
      description: $('#description').text(),
      tags: this.tags,
      categoryId: this.categoryId
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: $('#privacy-status option:selected').text()
    }
  };
  var uploader = new MediaUploader({
    baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos',
    file: file,
    token: this.accessToken,
    metadata: metadata,
    params: {
      part: Object.keys(metadata).join(',')
    },
    onError: function(data) {
      var message = data;
      // Assuming the error is raised by the YouTube API, data will be
      // a JSON string with error.message set. That may not be the
      // only time onError will be raised, though.
      try {
        var errorResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        message = errorResponse.error.message;
      } finally {
        alert(message);
      }
    }.bind(this),
    onProgress: function(data) {
      var currentTime = Date.now();
      var bytesUploaded = data.loaded;
      var totalBytes = data.total;
      // The times are in millis, so we need to divide by 1000 to get seconds.
      var bytesPerSecond = bytesUploaded / ((currentTime - this.uploadStartTime) / 1000);
      var estimatedSecondsRemaining = (totalBytes - bytesUploaded) / bytesPerSecond;
      var percentageComplete = (bytesUploaded * 100) / totalBytes;

      $('#upload-progress').attr({
        value: bytesUploaded,
        max: totalBytes
      });

      $('#percent-transferred').text(percentageComplete);
      $('#bytes-transferred').text(bytesUploaded);
      $('#total-bytes').text(totalBytes);

      $('.during-upload').show();
    }.bind(this),
    onComplete: function(data) {
      var uploadResponse = JSON.parse(data);
      this.videoId = uploadResponse.id;
      $('#video-id').text(this.videoId);
      $('.post-upload').show();
      this.pollForVideoStatus();
    }.bind(this)
  });
  // This won't correspond to the *exact* start of the upload, but it should be close enough.
  this.uploadStartTime = Date.now();
  uploader.upload();
};

UploadVideo.prototype.handleUploadClicked = function() {
  $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
  this.uploadFile($('#file').get(0).files[0]);
};

UploadVideo.prototype.pollForVideoStatus = function() {
  this.gapi.client.request({
    path: '/youtube/v3/videos',
    params: {
      part: 'status,player',
      id: this.videoId
    },
    callback: function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
        // The status polling failed.
        console.log(response.error.message);
        setTimeout(this.pollForVideoStatus.bind(this), STATUS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
      } else {
        var uploadStatus = response.items[0].status.uploadStatus;
        switch (uploadStatus) {
          // This is a non-final status, so we need to poll again.
          case 'uploaded':
            $('#post-upload-status').append('<li>Upload status: ' + uploadStatus + '</li>');
            setTimeout(this.pollForVideoStatus.bind(this), STATUS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
            break;
          // The video was successfully transcoded and is available.
          case 'processed':
            $('#player').append(response.items[0].player.embedHtml);
            $('#post-upload-status').append('<li>Final status.</li>');
            break;
          // All other statuses indicate a permanent transcoding failure.
          default:
            $('#post-upload-status').append('<li>Transcoding failed.</li>');
            break;
        }
      }
    }.bind(this)
  });
};
```

The associated [HTML](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.html), [CSS](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.css) and [JavaScript](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js) file (defining the MediaUploader class).

A complete Fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r6Lpwkbe/2/). Follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) to create a project and replace `YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE` in the Fiddle with the corresponding client id from the project.

Regarding AngularJS, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775656/how-to-use-api-key-with-youtube-in-angularjs-and-list-videos-in-a-playlist) to help you get started building a service for Angular.

Comment: What are the files i need to create for this example?. Any html file associated with this javascript code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the associated files. I edited my answer to include them. It is especially unclear in the example where the MediaUploader class comes from. This is defined in the added JS file.

Comment: Thank for your reply!!. Can you please add the running example? With associated HTML files?

Comment: I added a Fiddle to the answer,  just follow the steps to create a google developers console project (if you haven't done so already) and insert your client id in the code.

Comment: Is it possible to do with in angularJs?

Comment: I am not an expert in AngularJS, but it should be possible to create a service that you can inject in your controllers. I added a relevant link to the answer.

Comment: their documentation is horrible -- in the current api it looks nothing like this. everything is done with objects and methods that are not defined in the code, and at near the top of the api sections is a note to the effect "many examples assume you've made custom handlers for various actions in the code"