# Uploading videos to youtube into my channel through website?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Exploring [youtube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and I cannot tell if it's possible to upload videos of users into the site's youtube channel directly.

I did manage to upload a video to youtube but that video would be uploaded under the uploader rather than the sites channel.
used this question:

[Video Upload In Youtube APi using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713335/video-upload-in-youtube-api-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the documentation you linked to:

> The **onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel** parameter specifies the YouTube
>   channel ID of the channel to which a video is being added

Unfortunately, it also points out:

> Note: This parameter is intended exclusively for YouTube content
>   partners.

The criteria for becoming a "content partner" is available in this [overview](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851?hl=en) of the program.